# How to merge multiple (single column) rows into single string in SQL SERVER

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a requirement in which I have to merge multiple rows as a single string of a single column A. Ex: If A returns 4 rows what I want is 'row1,row2,row3,row4'.
Problem is these rows will be accepted by a single procedure parameter and I wonder whether this merging is possible on that parameter or not.

Comment: What version of SQL?

Comment: Follow the duplicate link to see options for doing this.  When you have tried a query, if it doesn't work then drop a comment here or open a new question.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, actually smells like an XY problem.   I think the real solution here is `Table Valued Parameters`.   Unless the receiving procedure can't be modified.